# How to search person with his latest job by his name in sql query in codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, greatest-n-per-group

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT user.*, job.*, max(job.End_Time) as END_time
    FROM user,job
    WHERE user.UID = job.UID and user.UID in( select UID from user where Name LIKE '%" .$search ."%')group by job.UID DESC");
```

I did this but it shown person first job.

Comment: what the criteria of having latest job ? job's auto increment id or any date column ?

Comment: job ID is auto increment with UID (user id). One user may have many job ID.

Answer (score 0):

You need another self join on your job table with max id of job per user in order to get the results as latest job or user ,when you use group by the non aggregated fields have indeterminate results, Also your sub query is of no use except to increase the load you can rewrite your query as below

```
SELECT 
  u.*,
  j.*
FROM
  `user` u,
JOIN job j ON u.UID = j.UID 
JOIN (SELECT UID,MAX(JID) JID FROM job GROUP BY UID) j1
   ON(j.UID = j1.UID AND j.JID = j1.JID)
WHERE u.Name LIKE '%" .$search ."%'
```

Comment: MAX(id) this id is come from where? I want to show his designation by his latest end_time. In job table column is JID, UID, Designation, Start_Time, End_Time

Comment: @MasudSarker from your job table to pick the latest job id for each user

Comment: Tnx for that . But it didn't work I don't know what the reason. Plz give me another solution

Comment: $q = $this->db->query("SELECT 
        u.*,
        j.*
      FROM
        user u,
      JOIN job j ON u.UID = j.UID 
      JOIN (SELECT UID,MAX(JID) id FROM job GROUP BY UID) j1
         ON(j.UID = j1.UID AND j.id = j1.id)
      WHERE u.Name LIKE '%" .$search ."%'"); I wrote this but it show error.